# Prove that the number $ \underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{(p-1) \mathrm{l}^{\prime} \mathrm{s}} $ is divisible by $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, repunit-numbers

**Question** -

Example 1.30. Let $p \geq 7$ be a prime. Prove that the number
$
\underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{(p-1) \mathrm{l}^{\prime} \mathrm{s}}
$
is divisible by $p$

Proof: We have
$
\underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{p-1^{\prime} \mathrm{s}}=\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9}
$
and the conclusion follows from Fermat's little theorem.

**But by FLT we get ${10^{p-1}-1} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ how we will get that $\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$?**

Comment: Well, $p \geq 7$, so that $p$ does not divide $9$. Hence, if $p$ divides $10^{p-1} - 1$, then it also divides $(10^{p-1}-1)/9$.

Comment: If you know $10^{p-1}-1 \equiv 0 \mod p$, then mutiplying by $9^{-1}$ (an integer such that $9\cdot 9^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ on both sides shows that $(10^{p-1}-1)/p \equiv (10^{p-1}-1)\cdot p^{-1} \equiv 0 \mod p$.

Comment: @Hayden but 9^(-1) is not integer, we can multiply both sides in congruence if it is an integer

Comment: Check it here for more detailed explanation.https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3663214/626107

Comment: @Ishan In modular arithmetic it is an integer (assuming $3\nmid p$).

Comment: @Ishan By $9^{-1}$ I mean an (not necessarily unique) integer $m$ such that $9\cdot m \equiv 1 \mod p$ (which exists since $p$ is a prime $\geq 7$ and hence is coprime with $9$). In other words, some representative of the inverse of $9$ (or, rather, its residue) in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, if that makes sense.

Comment: $\gcd(9,p) = 1$.

Comment: If $ak \equiv 0 \pmod n$ and $\gcd(k,n) =1$ then $a \equiv 0\pmod n$.

Comment: Bezout's lemma states that as $\gcd(9,p)=1$ there are integers $a,b$ so $9a +pb =1$.  So $9a \equiv 1\pmod p$.  We refer to $a$ as $9^{-1}$ because $9a \equiv 1\pmod p$.  So $9*1111....111 \equiv 0\pmod p$ so $a*9*1111....111 \equiv a*0\pmod p$ and $111...11\equiv 0\pmod p$. Ex: $p=7$ then $9*(4)+7*(-5)=1$ so we say $4\equiv 9^{-1}\pmod 7$ Because $4*9\equiv 1\pmod 7$.  And $10^6-1=9*111111\equiv 0\pmod 7$ so $4(10^6-1)=4*9*111111=36*111111\equiv 35*111111+111111\equiv 1111111\equiv 4*0\equiv 0\pmod 7$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ak \equiv 0 \pmod n$ and $\gcd(k,n) =1$ then $a \equiv 0\pmod n$.

Pf:  If $\gcd(k,n) =1$ then by Bezouts Lemma there are $x,y$ so that $kx + ny = 1$.  So $kx \equiv 1 \pmod n$.  So $ak \equiv 0 \pmod n$ then $akx \equiv 0x\pmod n$ but $akx\equiv a(kx) \equiv a\pmod n$.

.....

So $p$ is prime and $p \ge 7$ so $\gcd(p,9) = 1$.

And $9|10^{p-1} -1$.  And $10^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. So......

$10^{p-1}-1= 9*\underbrace{111...1}\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

So $\underbrace{111...1}\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

======

Alternatively.

$9|10^p-1 = 9999999....9$ and $p|10^p-1$. So the least common multiple of $9$ and $p$ will also divide $10^9-1$.

The least common multiple of $9$ and $p$ is $9p$ as $\gcd(p,9) =1$.

So $9p|10^p-1$ and so $p|\frac {10^p - 1}9$.

Comment: ohhh, yes i forgot that divisibility property.

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply
$$9 | (10^{p-1}-1) \ \ \text{and} \ \ p|(10^{p-1}-1)$$
So,
$$10^{p-1}-1=9pk$$
where $\gcd(9,p)=\gcd(9,k)=\gcd(p,k)=1$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$. So
$$\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9}=pk \implies p|\left(\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9}\right) \ \Box.$$

Note: $9 | (10^{p-1}-1)$ because of the factoring formula 
$$x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+ \dots + xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$
Plugging in $x=10$, $y=1$ and $n=p-1$ gives the conclusion.

Comment: thankyou very much, i forgot that divisibility theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By the geometric series sum formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
\underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{p-1^{\prime} \mathrm{s}}&=1+10+\dotsb+10^{p-2}
=\frac{10^{p-1}-1}{10-1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now this is clearly an integer, which means $9\mid 10^{p-1}-1$. 
Since $p\geq7$, $p\nmid9$, so for $p$ to divide $\underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{p-1^{\prime} \mathrm{s}} $ we need $p\mid10^{p-1}-1$, which follows since $\gcd(10,p)=1$, and so we may use FLT, $10^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$. Note it does not matter to us that $9$ divides into $10^{p-1}-1$, since $\gcd(p,9)=1$, so $p$ divides into some part of $\underbrace{11 \ldots 1}_{p-1^{\prime} \mathrm{s}} $ relatively prime to $9$.

Answer (score -1):

Since $p$ is not divisible by $3$, modulo $p$ we have that division by $9$ corresponds to multiplication by some constant. Which constant will depend on $p$, but for instance, for $p=7$ we have $\frac19\equiv 4$, and for $p=11$ we have $\frac19\equiv 5$.

This gives us $10^{p-1}-1\equiv 0\implies \frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9}\equiv 0$.